# Why can't I get type-specific information in my Sequence extension?

Tags: swift, swift3, iterator, sequence

Why does this work, where PageBreak is a NSManagedObject

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element : PageBreak {

    var landscape: [PageBreak] {
        return self.filter({ (pageBreak) -> Bool in
            return !pageBreak.isPortraitOrientation
        })
    }

    var portrait: [PageBreak] {
        return self.filter({ (pageBreak) -> Bool in
            return pageBreak.isPortraitOrientation
        })
    }
}
```

But not this:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element : String {
    var onlyDumbOnes: [String] {
        return self.filter({ (string) -> Bool in
            if string.hasPrefix("Dumb") {
                return true
            }
            return false
        })
    }
}
```

The compiler fails.
`Value of type 'Self.Iterator.Element' has no member 'hasPrefix'`

So it doesn't seem to know that we're dealing with String objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String` is a `struct` and not a `class` or a `protocol`, so the syntax `Iterator.Element : String` doesn't make sense since `Iterator.Element` can't be a subclass of `String` or implement the `protocol` `String`.  Instead, use `Iterator.Element == String`:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == String {
    var onlyDumbOnes: [String] {
        return self.filter { (string) -> Bool in
            if string.hasPrefix("Dumb") {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the way!  Correct.